# How to extract a IP address from JavaScript string data

Tags: javascript

I have string data aa = {"PC-lab-network-452":[{"version":4,"addr":"10.186.32.137","OS-EXT-IPS:type":"fixed","OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr":"fa:16:3e:39:38:ac"}]}

in javaScript  and I've to extract the exact IP address --10.186.32.137 from this data

I'm trying this command--

b = aa.match(\10.186.32.137\g) but it also matches the pattern like 10.186.32.13. I need to match the exact pattern. Any help to fix this?

Comment: Looks like JSON... why not `JSON.parse(aa)` if it's not already an object, and if it is index into it to get the value you want?

Comment: Once you parse it: `data['PC-lab-network-452'][0].addr`.

Comment: PC-lab-network-452 value is not static. It's changing in every call. That's why I've used converted it to sting data.

Comment: RegExps are used to match patterns, since you are trying to match a string you could use `aa.indexOf("10.186.32.137") > -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most simple regex pattern would be:

```js
const aa = `{"PC-lab-network-452":[{"version":4,"addr":"10.186.32.137","OS-EXT-IPS:type":"fixed","OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr":"fa:16:3e:39:38:ac"}]}`
const reg = new RegExp(/..\....\...\..../g)
const res = aa.match(reg)
console.log(res[0]);
```

but as posted in comments why not use JSON.parse?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string with [JSON.parse(STRING)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) then access your network object ("PC-lab-network-452") `JSON.parse(aa)["PC-lab-network-452"]` then access any valid array index `JSON.parse(aa)["PC-lab-network-452"][0]` then access the `addr` property `JSON.parse(aa)["PC-lab-network-452"][0].addr`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to solve this without regex. Try this :

```js
const a = {"PC-lab-network-452":[{"version":4,"addr":"10.186.32.137","OS-EXT-IPS:type":"fixed","OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr":"fa:16:3e:39:38:ac"}]};

Object.keys(a).forEach(item => {
    const ipExist = a[item].find(obj => obj.addr === "10.186.32.137");
    if (ipExist) {
        console.log(ipExist.addr);
    }
    else {
        console.log('IP not found');
    }
});
```

Comment: this will only work for exactly the same ip, no pattern is checked

Comment: @MWO Check the question ""I've to extract the exact IP address --10.186.32.137 from this data" He is not looking to extract all ip's

Comment: he also writes "I need to match the exact pattern", so its unclear what he needs